# Trying to use Flask-mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-mysql

I'm trying to get Flask to connect to a local MySQL but this keeps failing. I have tried multiple combinations based on other forums

```
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
from flask_mysql import MySQL
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

etc.

the error I get is the following

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.mysql
```

Running Windows 10 & Python3.5
I have pip installed flask-MySQL

********** **EDIT** ***********

With the help of the user @metmirr (Thank you!!!) the fix was to use a virtual environment, couldn't get it to work any other way! The answer and comments have been removed somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql.connector for accessing MySQL from Flask. For more [details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html) visit the link.

**Import MySQL Connector**

```
import mysql.connector
```

**Connect to local database**

```
def getMysqlConnection():
    return mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='test',user='root',password='root')
```

**To access the database**

```
db = getMysqlConnection()
sqlstr = "select * from test_table"
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute(sqlstr)
output_json = cur.fetchall()
```